# Integral of Complex Analytic function over general closed curves

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $O$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. To consider only simple cases, let $O$ be an open disk. Let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function such that $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$. Let $f$ be an analytic function on $O$

If $\gamma$ is a rectifiable curve, then $\int\limits_{\gamma} f = 0$.
I wondered what would happen if $\gamma$ was considered to be continuous function only. What can we say about $\int\limits_{\gamma} f$ then ? Does the integral exist? If so, what can we say about its value?

My knowledge of Complex Analysis is limited to introductory course. Any help would be appreciated. If there are some books to refer, stating the name would also help.

Comment: In that case there is nothing we can say about the value in general.

Comment: @K.defaoite Is there any example where integral doesn't exist?

Comment: If $f$ is entire and $\gamma$ is $C^1$ the integral will always exist. If $S\subset \Bbb{C}$ is some curve parameterized by $\gamma:[a,b]\to S$ then
$$\int_{S}f(z)\mathrm dz=\int_a^b (f\circ \gamma)(t)\cdot \gamma'(t)\mathrm dt$$

Answer (score -1):

This example works.
Take $f(z) = z$, which is a analytic function.
Define a curve $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as follows
$\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = 0$
$\gamma(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} $ for $n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 1$
For $x \in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$, $\gamma(x) = \frac{x-\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}}\gamma(\frac{1}{n+1}) + \frac{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}}\gamma(\frac{1}{n})  $.
We are simply joining $\gamma(\frac{1}{n+1})$ and $\gamma(\frac{1}{n})$ by a straight line.

Then $\int\limits_{\gamma} f$ doesn't exist.